# Tag not removed after .decompose()

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wanted to remove the text inside of the strong tags so I did this:

```
for strong in soup.find('strong'):
    strong.decompose()
```

But when I opened the file the last one wasn't deleted:

[image: html]

Comment: I think you want `strong.unwrap()`?

Comment: Nothing changed the last one wasn't deleted again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `find()` which returns only the first match found. This is why you can see that the first `strong` is gone but the second one isn't. Use `find_all()` instead which will remove all the `strong` tags.

```
for strong in soup.find_all('strong'):
    strong.decompose()
```