# cannot decompose <tr class="thead">

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have the following table

```
<table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table now_sortable sticky_table eq1 re1 le1" id="divs_standings_W" data-cols-to-freeze=",1">
    <caption>&nbsp; Table</caption>
    

   <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
   <thead>      
      <tr>
         <th aria-label="Western Conference" data-stat="team_name" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc left">Western Conference</th>
         <th aria-label="Wins" data-stat="wins" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="Wins">W</th>
         <th aria-label="Losses" data-stat="losses" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="Losses">L</th>
         <th aria-label="Win-Loss Percentage" data-stat="win_loss_pct" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="Win-Loss Percentage">W/L%</th>
         <th aria-label="GB" data-stat="gb" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc right" data-tip="Games Behind">GB</th>
         <th aria-label="Points Per Game" data-stat="pts_per_g" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="Points Per Game">PS/G</th>
         <th aria-label="Opponent Points Per Game" data-stat="opp_pts_per_g" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="Opponent Points Per Game">PA/G</th>
         <th aria-label="Simple Rating System" data-stat="srs" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="Simple Rating System; a team rating that takes into account average point differential and strength of schedule. The rating is denominated in points above/below average, where zero is average.">SRS</th>
</tr>
      </thead>
<tbody><tr class="thead" data-row="0"><th colspan="8"><strong>Northwest Division</strong></th></tr>
<tr class="full_table" data-row="1"><th scope="row" class="left " data-stat="team_name"><a href="/teams/UTA/2021.html">Utah Jazz</a>*</th><td class="right " data-stat="wins">52</td><td class="right " data-stat="losses">20</td><td class="right " data-stat="win_loss_pct">.722</td><td class="right " data-stat="gb">—</td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_per_g">116.4</td><td class="right " data-stat="opp_pts_per_g">107.2</td>
```

i am trying to scrape the table and remove  use .decompose(), but it didn't removed

this is my work:

```
dfs_player = []
for year in years:
    with open("player/{}.html".format(year)) as f:
        page = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    soup.find("tr", class_="thead").decompose()
    player_table = soup.find(id="div_per_game_stats")
    player = pd.read_html(str(player_table))[0]
    player['Year'] = year
    
    dfs_player.append(player)
```

and here is the example url = https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2023_per_game.html

can you guys help me, please?

**I got the answer, here you can see the answer I wanted :)) : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484080/22418778)**

Comment: Whats the desired output?

Comment: there is a column range that I don't want to retrieve, which means the class name "thead"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about thead is a class, i think it's more a tag, you can test this code, if it works:

```
soup.find("thead").decompose()
```

Or this code:

```
for tr in soup.find("thead").find_all("tr"):
    tr.decompose()
```

So for the first code, the method `soup.find("thead")` will search the first occurrence of the specified HTML element (in this case: html tag **thead** ) from the parsed HTML document (**soup**), and then it removes the first element **thead** and all its contents from the HTML structure.

For the second code, this method `soup.find("thead").find_all("tr")` locates also the first **thead** element, and then within the found **thead** element, it finds all **tr** elements. And with the `for` loop, it will iterate over all those **tr** tags individually (the ones found in first **thead** tag), and decompose all **tr** and also their contents.

The difference is that in the first code , **thead** is removed with its content, but in the second code, **thead** is not removed, just the **tr** tags inside it, that are removed.

Comment: Hey! You should add more details to your answer, and explain why these things work. This will help others learn instead of just copy-pasting.

Comment: i'm not mention a tag <thead>, but i'm mention a class name "thead", you can see there is a <tbody> <tr class="thead" ...>, I apologise for not explaining in detail :')

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, why don't you just ask `Pandas` to read the actual page HTML source and find the `<table>` by itself? This can be done with the [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html) method:

```py
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2023_per_game.html'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
print(dfs[0])
```

Print:

```
      Rk            Player Pos Age   Tm   G  ...   AST  STL  BLK  TOV   PF   PTS
0      1  Precious Achiuwa   C  23  TOR  55  ...   0.9  0.6  0.5  1.1  1.9   9.2
1      2      Steven Adams   C  29  MEM  42  ...   2.3  0.9  1.1  1.9  2.3   8.6
2      3       Bam Adebayo   C  25  MIA  75  ...   3.2  1.2  0.8  2.5  2.8  20.4
3      4      Ochai Agbaji  SG  22  UTA  59  ...   1.1  0.3  0.3  0.7  1.7   7.9
4      5      Santi Aldama  PF  22  MEM  77  ...   1.3  0.6  0.6  0.8  1.9   9.0
..   ...               ...  ..  ..  ...  ..  ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...
700  535    Thaddeus Young  PF  34  TOR  54  ...   1.4  1.0  0.1  0.8  1.6   4.4
701  536        Trae Young  PG  24  ATL  73  ...  10.2  1.1  0.1  4.1  1.4  26.2
702  537    Omer Yurtseven   C  24  MIA   9  ...   0.2  0.2  0.2  0.4  1.8   4.4
703  538       Cody Zeller   C  30  MIA  15  ...   0.7  0.2  0.3  0.9  2.2   6.5
704  539       Ivica Zubac   C  25  LAC  76  ...   1.0  0.4  1.3  1.5  2.9  10.8

[705 rows x 30 columns]
```

Comment: but if you look deeper, there is even a column name that is also part of the data :')